# Subclassing a UIView

Tags: swift, class, uiview, subclass, init

I am trying to subclass a UIView with a custom initializer but am running into multiple errors.

```
class ProgressAlertView: UIView {

    var title: String

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        alertLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        alertLayout()
    }

    convenience init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.init(title: title)
    }
}
```

The code above will result in multiple error messages, among others for my variable title in the convenience init: 'self' used in property access 'title' before 'self.init' call

Swift however requires that all initializers in super class must be called after one initializes other instance variables. So the error must lie somewhere else.

Highly appreciate a tip here.

Comment: `init(title: String)` is calling itself!

Comment: Isn't that what it's supposed to do? Mind elaborating?

Comment: This will result in recursion - the init calls itself, which in turn calls itself, which in turn… etc,

Comment: You should override didMoveToSuperview method to customize your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you expect to happen in…

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    alertLayout()
}
```

and

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    alertLayout()
}
```

You have a non-optional instance variable `title`. How is it supposed to get a value in these 2 cases?

And in your 3rd `init`…

```
convenience init(title: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.init(title: title)
}
```

`init(title: String)` calls `init(title: String)`, which in turn calls `init(title: String)`, etc. You're in infinite recursion territory.

If you want to instantiate the view in code, you'll need something like…

```
init(title: String, frame: CGRect) {
    self.title = title
    super.init(frame: frame)
    alertLayout()
}
```

and you'll also need to implement

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

If you're using this in a storyboard / nib, then you'll need…

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.title = ""
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

and then assign a value to `title` afterwards

Comment: You could keep the `init(title:)` initializer as convenience if you give `title` a default value, e.g. `var title = ""`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. The syntax for initializers when subclassing wasn't very intuitive to me so this was very helpful. Thanks!